# Measure response time for an API

Tags: jmeter, response-time

I have 416 webservice API's to test . I am loading those url's from a CSV file . my test need to find an API which takes more than 2 sec to respond . I couldn't find a way to measure response time for an API .

I am using

```
     Thread Users - 416 
     Ramp up Period - 1
     Loop Count - 1
```

I have tried "View Results in Table" listener which shows the sample time . But the sample time does not show individual response time .

Please let me know if you find any solution ?

Comment: I figured out the problem . When i use Thread as 416 , 416 threads created in parallel which makes the listener to calculate the sample time with threads response .Now, I made the Loop Count as 416 and Thread as 1, so only one thread created and jmeter go through every row one by one in the CSV file . so 416 API's tested with proper response time for an API .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use listeners  as [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) in Load test because it consumes a lot of resources

> this visualizer uses a lot of memory.

Use [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) instead, defined it with 2000 milliseconds in your case

> Duration Assertion tests that each response was received within a given amount of time. Any response that takes longer than the given number of milliseconds (specified by the user) is marked as a failed response.

Answer (score 1):

Add listener `Summary report` which has columns as average, minimum and maximum response time taken by a hit.You can also save this report by clicking on `Save Table data` button.

Also, add `View Results Tree` listener in which `Sampler Result` tab has all the details corresponding to that hit.

Answer (score 1):

On the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)) there is `Timeouts` section where you can define maximum value for establishing the connection and/or getting the response.

[image]

If JMeter fails to get the response within the time frame (in [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond)) the relevant sampler will be marked as failed.

In order to see individual response times - add the variable from the CSV file as HTTP Request label (or prefix or postfix) - this way you will see the associated URLs in the [listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) and in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) :

[image]